# The statevector of three-qubit bit-flip encoding circuit for entangled state

Tags: qiskit, error-correction

I was trying to implement a three-qubit bit-flip code for shared entangled state. I was curious to analyze this mathematically, but the problem is I can't calculate the statevector after encoding. Here is the circuit:
[image]

I used Qiskit to calculate the statevector, but it turns out to be 0's for every qubit. I am very confused because I don't know if this is valid or not!

[image]

Could you please guide me a bit? Also, should this circuit have higher fidelity? Please comment on this as well.

Comment: This is certainly not the output that you should be getting for the circuit you've displayed. (It should be $(|000000\rangle+|111111\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$.) I'm not a qiskit expert, but I'm sure the experts on this site would find it helpful to see the whole code that you've written to define `bit_flip_qc`.

Comment: I have found the solution. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Statevector.evolve()`<sup>[[1]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.evolve.html)</sup> returns the evolution result. It does not change the instance it called in. So all what you need is to change your code to become:

```
av = Statevector.from_label('000000')
result = av.evolve(bit_flip_qc)
result.data
```

Comment: Wow, it's working now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make 2 repetition logical qubits first and entangle them with logical CNOT operator. you can check every single steps separately.

1. Make $|+_L\rangle_{Alice} = {1\over\sqrt{2}} (|000 \rangle + |111 \rangle )$ and  $|0_L\rangle_{bob} = |000 \rangle$
2. Apply three CNOT operators transversally
3. Final state will be ${1\over\sqrt{2}} (|000_{Alice}000_{bob} \rangle + |111_{Alice}111_{bob} \rangle )$